# Multisite Enabling a Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a table (table A) that will have a number of columns(of course) and there will be another table (table B) that holds metadata associated to rows in table A.

I am working with a multi site implementation that has one database for the whole shabang. Rows in table A could belong to any number of sites but must belong to at least one.

The problem I have is I am not sure what the best practice is for defining what site each row in table A belongs to. I want performance and scalability. There is no finite number of sites going forward. Rows in table A could belong to any number of sites in the future. Right now there are only 3.

My initial thoughts are to have a primary site ID in Table A and then metadata in table B will have rows defining additional sites as needed.

Another thought is to have a column in Table A for each site and it is a boolean as to wether it belongs to that site.

Lastly I have thought about having another table to map rows in Table A to each site.

What is the best way to associate rows in a table with any number of sites with performance and scalability in mind?

Comment: I can't speak to what would be best, but do not go with the bool route. The reason for this is that if there are 20 sites and one row only belongs to 1 of the 20, that leaves 19 values telling you nothing but no. As your data scales, that will eat space and possibly impact performance.

Comment: Is there a reason why checking for duplicates on update or insert to table A would be preferable to adding a unique index that includes the data source along with what you're already proposing as an external key? It might help to get to concrete definitions to discuss them.